# How do I add spaces between characters in an output statement when I am multiplying

Tags: python, for-loop

For this program, the goal is to output a right triangle based on a user specified height triangle_height and symbol triangle_char. We are meant to create a triangle out of a user-inputted height and character, created by repeating a string to make a new string. So far I have:

```
triangle_char = input('Enter a character:\n')
triangle_height = int(input('Enter triangle height:\n'))
print('')
for x in range(1, triangle_height + 1):
    print(x * triangle_char)
```

Which runs and outputs a tringle of the inputted height made of the inputted character however, the printed triangle is supposed to have spaces between every character

```
(ex: *      not:  *
     * *          **
     * * *        ***
```

How do I get spaces in between the printed characters?

Comment: `print(" ".join(triangle_char * x))`

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a `' '` character after triangle_char like so:

```
for x in range(1, triangle_height + 1):
    print(x * (triangle_char + ' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not produce trailing spaces at the ends of the lines.
Instead it uses the very pythonic way of joining lists

```
triangle_height = 5
triangle_char = "*"

for x in range(triangle_height):
    print(" ".join(triangle_char * (x+1)))
```